# How can I create all possibilities from different arrays?

Tags: php, recursion

Yes I know maybe the title is so similar but it's not same than the others. I think it can be done with a recursive function. But I could not do. For example I have three different arrays:

```
array('1')
array('a','b')
array('x', 'y', 'z')
```

I want to create a new array or output like this;

```
array(
  '1',
  '1a',
  '1b',
  '1x',
  '1y',
  '1z',
  '1ax',
  '1ay',
  '1az',
  '1bx', 
  '1by',
  '1bz'
)
```

And the main problem is I don't know how many arrays come out of the first array.

Comment: You're looking for "[permutations](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+php+create+permutations+from+arrays)". Or just add an empty string to [2], [3] and write two loops.

Comment: What do you mean "just add an empty string"?

Comment: He means make `array('1', '', '')` so you can do something like `for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)` for each of the arrays.

Personally, I would nest some `foreach` loops as Dennis mentioned in his answer.

Comment: My aim is not to doing loop for each array.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order important? If it isn’t this should do the trick:

```
$array1 = array('1');
$array2 = array('a','b');
$array3 = array('x', 'y', 'z');

$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $val) {
    foreach ($array2 as $val2) {
        foreach ($array3 as $val3) {
            $result[] = $val.$val2.$val3;
        }
        $result[] = $val.$val2;
    }
    $result[] = $val;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Actually yes important but it is not my main problem. Because I don't know how many arrays come out of the first array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Currently there are three separate arrays. If this number is dynamic, how do you know how many arrays there are?

Comment: I mean sometimes maybe 4 separete arrays or more than. Then you will need to write loop for each array. But I don't do that.

Comment: this code giving this : Array( [0] => 1ax [1] => 1ay [2] => 1az [3] => 1a [4] => 1bx [5] => 1by [6] => 1bz [7] => 1b [8] => 1)

Answer (score 0):

my dear fellow

i just have a chance to look for answer.
it might be like this or need to make a recursive function to get the result for unknown count of arrays

```
<?php

$array1 = array('1');
$array2 = array('a','b');
$array3 = array('x', 'y', 'z');

//$max = max(count($array1), count($array2), count($array3));

$result = array();
$temp = array();

foreach ($array1 as $val) {
    $result[] = $val;
    foreach ($array2 as $val2) {
        $result[] = $val.$val2;
        foreach ($array3 as $val3) {
            $result[] = $val.$val3;
            $temp[] = $val.$val2.$val3;
        }
    }
}

$result = array_merge($result, $temp);
$result = array_unique($result);
?>
<pre>
<?php 
print_r(array_values($result)); 
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is java version

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Rec {

    static void perm(Vector<String> all_possibilities,Vector<Vector<String>> total){
         Vector<String> stack = new Vector<String>();
         perm(all_possibilities, stack,total,0);
    }

    static void perm(Vector<String> all_possibilities, Vector<String> stack,Vector<Vector<String>> total, int index ){
        if (total.size() == index)
            return;
        Vector<String> current = total.get(index);
        for (int i = 0; i < current.size(); i++) {
            String item = current.get(i);
            stack.add(item);
            String stack_str = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < stack.size(); j++) {
                stack_str += stack.get(j)+"-";
            }
            all_possibilities.add(stack_str);
            perm(all_possibilities, stack, total, index + 1);
            stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector<String> v1 = new Vector<String>();
        v1.add("1");
        v1.add("2");
        v1.add("3");
        Vector<String> v2 = new Vector<String>();
        v2.add("a");
        v2.add("b");
        v2.add("c");
        v2.add("d");
        v2.add("e");
        Vector<String> v3 = new Vector<String>();
        v3.add("A");
        v3.add("B");
        v3.add("C");
        v3.add("D");
        v3.add("E");


        Vector<Vector<String>> total = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        total.add(v1);
        total.add(v2);
        total.add(v3);


        Vector<String> all_possibilities = new Vector<String>();
        perm(all_possibilities, total);

        for (int i = 0; i < all_possibilities.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(all_possibilities.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, but this question is regarding PHP, not Java.